# Creating an index on result of query

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Is it possible to create an index on the results of something like the following? Value is another jsonb obj.

```
SELECT data_timestamp, key, value FROM hit_count CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data);
```

Comment: which query are you wanting to speed up?

Comment: @jjanes the super query that uses the above as a sub query. I want to index `value` from `jsonb_each()` given a key set

Comment: @jjanes actually I want to index on key too...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**, you can index JSON data, for instance, you can read about it here: https://scalegrid.io/blog/using-jsonb-in-postgresql-how-to-effectively-store-index-json-data-in-postgresql/

You will need to study GIN indexes, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-intro.html

Alternatively, you could create a table (or view or materialized view) to store the result of your query with possibly also creating a trigger to update them whenever `hit_count` records are being added/removed/updated.